# SQL IN operator with alias selector not working only return first match

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Im trying to return a set of data with php where a specific id matches in a set of ids in the database.

i have to following code:

```
$id = 2;

$stmGetScoutUnits = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM scout_units as su WHERE '.$id.' IN (su.greenhouse_ids) AND user_id = 1');

$stmGetScoutUnits->execute();

$scoutUnits = $stmGetScoutUnits->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

var_dump($scoutUnits);
```

database looks a follow:

```
scout_units
+---------+---------------+-------+
| user_id | greenhouse_ids| name  |
+---------+---------------+-------+
|    1    | 1,2           | test  |
|    1    | 1,2           | test2 |
|    1    | 3,4           | test3 |
+---------+---------------+-------+
```

When i have id 1 it returns sql rows 1 and 2 but when i have id 2 it returns nothing. i have no id whats going on here? any idea?

Comment: your right! edited.

Comment: Sorry my mistake i edited the question it should be okey now

Comment: Use `FIND_IN_SET()` http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-find_in_set/ not `IN()`.

Comment: Fix your data!  Don't store comma-delimited lists in strings.  Use SQL correctly!

Comment: @Julez What is the `user_id` column type here? No idea why that column has all 1's. Post your db schema. and what does var_dump reveal from Rajdeep's answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you need here is MySQL's [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) function, so your query should be like this:

```
SELECT * 
FROM scout_units as su 
WHERE FIND_IN_SET('.$id.', su.greenhouse_ids) 
AND user_id = 1
```

And your prepared statement should be like this:

```
$stmGetScoutUnits = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM scout_units as su WHERE FIND_IN_SET('.$id.', su.greenhouse_ids) AND user_id = 1');
```

Comment: [GMTA...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39943535/sql-in-operator-with-alias-selector-not-working-only-return-first-match#comment67167620_39943535) I didn't see your answer.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Coincidentally we posted(comment and answer) at the exact(almost) same time. ;-)

Comment: Pretty much *lol* but you were typing it up as I was Googling ;-)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. i still get a empty set where $id = 2

Comment: @Julez See the fiddle, [http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffbabf/1](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ffbabf/1). It's working as expected.

Comment: Hi, thank you very much its working now. appreciate it!